# Serial Messages Issue

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm receiving in my serial port the message "Hello World!CRLF" (no quotes) at every 1 second, and I'm using ReadExisting() to read the message, but I can't understand why I'm receiving lots of "\0" before every character.

[image: Visual Studio Debug]

PuTTy seems to handle the messages just fine, so my code must be the problem. Could someone please help me to figure this out?

[image: PuTTY]

Part of my code:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort(cbPort.Text);
            _serialPort.BaudRate = Int32.Parse(cbBaudrate.SelectedItem.ToString());
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.Open();
            if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    ReadSerialData();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception er){}

    }
    private void ReadSerialData()
    {
        try
        {
            ReadSerialDataThread = new Thread(ReadSerial);
            ReadSerialDataThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }

    private void ReadSerial()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_serialPort.BytesToRead >= 0)
            {
                readserialvalue = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                ShowSerialData(readserialvalue);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }


    public delegate void ShowSerialDatadelegate(string r);

    private void ShowSerialData(string s)
    {
        if (rtb_msg.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ShowSerialDatadelegate SSDD = ShowSerialData;
            Invoke(SSDD, s);
        }
        else
        {
            rtb_msg.AppendText(readserialvalue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your constructor setup for your ``_serialPort`` object in the ``ReadSerial()`` method?

Comment: I've just added the constructor part and a little bit else to the post. Thanks for helping!

Comment: The problem is located at the other end of the wire.  You can't see it with Putty because it doesn't print anything for a binary zero.  For some strange reason the transmitter is sending big-endian utf16 encoded text.  You want to investigate that first, given that the choice is so unusual.  The workaround on your end is _serialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;  It *might* be little-endian.

Comment: @HansPassant woah! The '\0' are gone! Since the transmitter is a PLC (industrial controller) it may be some kind of standard. But unfortunately my richtext box still empty, any thoughts on what might be causing it?

Comment: Just more bugs.  It must be rtb_msg.AppendText(s);  And the thread quits too soon, BytesToRead is normally 0, serial ports are slow.

Comment: @HansPassant, When you say that my thread quits too soon you mean the Thread.Sleep(1);? Because I tried to increase the value to 1000 and even comment this line and it didn't worked.
The weirdest thing is, if I put a break point and run the program step by step I can see briefly the richtextbox flash with the messages, but I if remove the breakpoint the box remains empty...

Comment: This is probably because the software loop is reading without exiting the button1_Click event handler. Let's leave the reading and display on the screen to the DataReceived event handler, and with button1_Click, only open and register the DataReceived event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I was using a Thread to handle the incoming messages but now I'm using SerialDataReceivedEvent to call a Delegate so it can update the Rich Textbox and it worked just fine!
The only weird thing now is.... Now half of my messages have these japanese symbols and I can't understand why. Look what I'm getting:

Hello World!
䠀攀氀氀漀 圀漀爀氀搀ℍHello World!

Answer (score 1):

As sugested by @Hans Passant changing the encoding to BigEndian solved the main issue.
Still getting lots of invalid unicode chars, but I think is best to open another thread. Thank you all for the support.

```
        _serialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to read from the serial port even if there are 0 bytes to be read? If not, you might want to try changing:
`while (_serialPort.BytesToRead >= 0)`
to
`while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)`
I suspect you may be reading from the serial port with 0 bytes to be read, which could return a null (`\0`) value

Comment: Good idea! But it didn't worked, same '\0' next to every char. The funniest thing is that nothing is being "printed" at my richtext box.